# find all inner grid points of a polygon made up from neighbouring grid points

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection, point

I have list of Points (int x, int y).
together they form areas, I check if this area is closed and then I need to get inner area formed by all positions that are inside this area.

example area:

[image]

Only idea I had is to convert this area to vector and check every point if it is inside polygon or not, counting intersections of polygon a axis's of point.

But I don't think it would be the most efficient way to do it.

other idea was to first get all points that are outside, I start from corners (if corner is not part of list of points, then is 100% empty), add all neighbor points that are empty and repeat.
then all points that aren't outside and aren't in highlighted list are inside.

but again, it feels somehow cumbersome...

Comment: Sounds a lot like a [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull).

Comment: Are these areas always simple or can they have holes inside like the letter O?

Comment: 1. Do you want to find the area of bounded figure or the quantity of points inside it ? 2. What exactly means the area is closed ? Does it mean that its shape is either parallel to coordinate lines or forms 45 deg. angle with them ?

Comment: @Dukeling thanks, it looks like this may be the solution, I take a better look at it.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze it can have holes in it.

Comment: @GrigorGevorgyan 1. I actually do need list of points inside it. 2. sorry for my english, I meant all point are connected and form a closed circle.

Comment: Well, then you might edit the title to something like `find all inner grid points of a polygon made up from neighbouring grid points`

Comment: Use a sweep line to build an interval tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find all inner grid points of grid polygon, one can exploit these observations:

1. for each inner grid point (x,y) also (x,y+0.5) and (x,y-0.5) are inner points.
2. the lines defined by `y=n+0.5` have simple intersections with the grid polygon

This leads to the following algorithm:

1. As a prerequisite one needs all non-horizontal (i.e. vertical and diagonal) polygon edges, actually only the x-coords of the centers in ascending order for each (second) mid-row.
2. The grid is scanned at each second horizontal "mid-line", i.e. `y=2n+0.5`, where n is from a sufficient range of integers s.t. the polygon is "covered", see the blue lines in the scetch.
3. Starting from the left all intersections with the polygon (i.e. the non-horizontal edges) and all inner points of the form (m,2n+0.5) are to be detected, see the red and green circles (this is done by iterating over the x-coors of the edges' centers)
4. Now the vertical grid neighbours (m,2n) and (m,2n+1) of inner points (m,2n+0.5) are inner points, if they are not on the boundary, see the green points in the scetch.

[image: AlgoScetch_innerPoints]

Here is some pseudo code (C++/python inspired :-) ):

```
list<Point> polygon; // given polygon as list of neighbouring grid points

// get centers of non-horizontal edges organized by line
map<int, set<float> > edgeCentersX; // for each scan line the x-coords of edges in ascending order

p_i = polygon[0]
yMin, yMax =  999999, -999999
for (i=1; i<polygon.size(); ++i)
    p_i1 = polygon[i] // next point after p_i
    if (p_i.x == p_i1.x)
        continue // horizontal edges can be ignored
    yMin_i = min(p_i.y, p_i1.y)
    if (yMin_i % 2 == 1)
        continue // we only need to look at each second mid-row
    if (yMin_i < yMin)
        yMin = yMin_i
    if (yMin_i > yMax)
        yMax = yMin_i
    cx = 0.5*(p_i.x+p_i1.x)
    edgeCentersX[yMin_i].insert(cx) // store edge center (yMin_i+0.5, cx)
    p_i = p_i1

list<Point> innerPoints
for (y=yMin; y<= yMax; y+=2)
    inside = false
    cx_i = edgeCentersX[y][0]
    for (i=1; i<edgeCentersX[y].size(); ++i)
        cx_i1 = edgeCentersX[y][i]
        inside = !inside
        if (!inside)
            continue
        for (x=floor(cx_i)+1; x<cx_i1; ++x)
            pLower = Point(y,x)
            if (!polygon.contains(pLower))
                innerPoints.append(pLower)
            pUpper = Point(y+1,x)
            if (!polygon.contains(pUpper))
                innerPoints.append(pUpper)
```

Comment: thanks!, looks interesting, will test it out tonight together with graham scan algorithm (as suggested by Dukeling) to see what works better. Your solution looks easier, will see if it works with all cases.

Answer (score 0):

[Pick's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) might be the formula you are looking for. It allows rather simple computation of the area for a polygon whose corners are grid points (i.e. have integer coordinates).

Comment: sorry, I may have asked the question wrongly, I don't need to calculate area mathematically, I need to get list of Points that are inside.

Comment: Ok, and exactly the number of points inside is one of the inputs to Pick's formula :-) So you would be left with the same problem.